# Apache prevent default server name

Tags: apache

For some reasons the domain used by my host is showing up on google results for my site even though I don't have any wildcard entries in my httpd.conf file

I have

```
NameVirtualHost 78.45.45.67:80
```

And

```
<VirtualHost 78.45.45.676:80>
DocumentRoot /home/mysite/public_html
ServerName www.mysite.com
ServerAlias mysite.com
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/error_log

Options ExecCGI


RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
RewriteRule .* - [F]

</VirtualHost>
```

But the site can be accessed from myserver.myhostingcomany.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache will use the first `<VirtualHost>` block to respond to requests that do not otherwise match another `VirtualHost` block.  So if you want to make your site inaccessible as `myserver.myhostingcompany.com`, make an explicit entry for it:

```
<VirtualHost 78.45.45.676:80>
  ServerName myserver.myhostingcomany.com

  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

If you place this *before* your entry for `www.mysite.com`, it will be used to fulfill requests for any hostname that does not match either `www.mysite.com` or `mysite.com`.